# Why won't my custom view scroll when using Scroller?

Tags: android, android-scroll

I'm trying to use Scroller to move a custom view, but the view doesn't move. Can anyone help me find what's wrong with my code?

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Scroller mScroller;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mScroller = new Scroller(context);
    }

    public void smoothScrollTo(int destX, int destY) {
        int scrollX = getScrollX();
        int deltaX = destX - scrollX;

        int scrollY = getScrollY();
        int deltaY = destY - scrollY;

        mScroller.startScroll(scrollX, scrollY, deltaX, deltaY, 1000);

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            int currX = mScroller.getCurrX();
            int currY = mScroller.getCurrY();

            Log.d("SCROLL", "currX = " + currX + ", currY = " + currY);

            scrollTo(currX, currY);
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CustomView mCustomView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCustomView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
    }

    public void onStart(View view) {
        mCustomView.smoothScrollTo(410, 200);
    }
}
```

layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.qihoo.scrollerdemo.MainActivity">

    <com.sample.scrollerdemo.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:background="#ff0"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


    <Button
        android:onClick="onStart"
        android:text="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @Thilek my codes are copied from a Android Book, and I just try to extend it from ScrollView, it doesn't work.

Comment: your Scroller code seems to be correct. I believe the issue is probably on your `draw` code. If you look at the source of the `View` class, `getScrollX()` or `scrollTo(x,y)` is just a set/get for an internal variable. During your `onDraw` you must use `getScroll` and change the drawing accordingly. How is your `Log`? can you see the values? (source of `View`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java)

Comment: From my logs, the values are correct. and I didn't override OnDraw method my codes.

Comment: So what are you expecting to be "scrolled" if the view is not drawing anything on the screen?